# Django: use urlresolver to set cookie path

Tags: django, cookies, django-settings

I wrote a webservices application over django. This application can be found as several instances on our servers.

For example:

```
http://server1/testapp/
http://server2/sandboxapp/
http://server2/productionapp/
```

The app instances are hosted on apache2 through mod_wsgi.

I use cookie authentication for all of these instances, and would like the cookies for each not to overlap with the others. I need to set the SESSION_COOKIE_PATH value.

It happens that I don't know beforehands the URLs behind which the application is deployed. So I'd like to use a reverse url to guess that value.

My main `urls.py` looks like this:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
     url(r'^$', view_server_root, {}, name='server_root'),
    ),
# here I also includes urls from the various sub-apps
for app in apps:
    urlpatterns.append(url(urlprefix,  include(app.urls))
```

I added this bit after all urls are loaded:

```
from django.core import urlresolvers
from django.conf import settings
settings.SESSION_COOKIE_PATH = urlresolvers.reverse('server_root')
```

Unfortunately `urlresolvers.reverse('server_root')` returns `/` and not the expected, for example, `/testapp/`. My cookies overlap if I log in to each instance.

Though, later on in the application usage, I use `django.db.models.permalink` for some views, which returns me a correct prefixed URL (e.g. `/testapp/page/465`).

There may be something with the context that is missing while executing `urls.py`.

Any ideas?

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You [shouldn't change Django settings at runtime](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/settings/#altering-settings-at-runtime). If you're using Django 1.4 or later, you might be able to use [`reverse_lazy`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#reverse-lazy) and set `SESSION_COOKIE_PATH` in your settings.py.

```
SESSION_COOKIE_PATH = reverse_lazy('server_root')
```